# LaTeX fails to hyphenate rather common english words

Tags: hyphenation, english

I encountered problem with LaTeX hyphenation. Because it happened for the first time, I presume that the mistake is done by me, not by packages.

Nevertheless, I cannot find what is wrong with my code.

[Edit]
Example to compile:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\section{Test}
But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of of attenuation I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness.
\end{document}
```

The PDF is builded by `Pdflatex`

The output is:
[image: The problem with attenuation hyphenation]

As you can see, the word `attenuation` is wrongly hyphenated (probably not hyphenated at all).

Help me spot my mistake.
Additionally, I will be grateful if you point any bad habits in my code.
P.S. I've checked [log of known exceptions](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb33-1/tb103hyf.pdf), the `attenuation` is not present on this list, so the error is obviously on my side.

[Edit2] Logfile (I deleted some full paths to make my question less than 30000 chars):

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6600) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.2.19)  20 FEB 2018 13:52
entering extended mode
**./temp.tex
(temp.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 0 language(s) loaded.
(/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/size12.clo
File: size12.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks14
\inpenc@posthook=\toks15

(utf8.def
File: utf8.def 2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
Now handling font encoding OML ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OML
Now handling font encoding T1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding T1

(t1enc.dfu
File: t1enc.dfu 2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
defining Unicode char U+00A0 (decimal 160)
defining Unicode char U+00A1 (decimal 161)
defining Unicode char U+00A3 (decimal 163)
defining Unicode char U+00AB (decimal 171)
defining Unicode char U+00AD (decimal 173)
defining Unicode char U+00BB (decimal 187)
defining Unicode char U+00BF (decimal 191)
defining Unicode char U+00C0 (decimal 192)
defining Unicode char U+00C1 (decimal 193)
defining Unicode char U+00C2 (decimal 194)
defining Unicode char U+00C3 (decimal 195)
defining Unicode char U+00C4 (decimal 196)
defining Unicode char U+00C5 (decimal 197)
defining Unicode char U+00C6 (decimal 198)
defining Unicode char U+00C7 (decimal 199)
defining Unicode char U+00C8 (decimal 200)
defining Unicode char U+00C9 (decimal 201)
defining Unicode char U+00CA (decimal 202)
defining Unicode char U+00CB (decimal 203)
defining Unicode char U+00CC (decimal 204)
defining Unicode char U+00CD (decimal 205)
defining Unicode char U+00CE (decimal 206)
defining Unicode char U+00CF (decimal 207)
defining Unicode char U+00D0 (decimal 208)
defining Unicode char U+00D1 (decimal 209)
defining Unicode char U+00D2 (decimal 210)
defining Unicode char U+00D3 (decimal 211)
defining Unicode char U+00D4 (decimal 212)
defining Unicode char U+00D5 (decimal 213)
defining Unicode char U+00D6 (decimal 214)
defining Unicode char U+00D8 (decimal 216)
defining Unicode char U+00D9 (decimal 217)
defining Unicode char U+00DA (decimal 218)
defining Unicode char U+00DB (decimal 219)
defining Unicode char U+00DC (decimal 220)
defining Unicode char U+00DD (decimal 221)
defining Unicode char U+00DE (decimal 222)
defining Unicode char U+00DF (decimal 223)
defining Unicode char U+00E0 (decimal 224)
defining Unicode char U+00E1 (decimal 225)
defining Unicode char U+00E2 (decimal 226)
defining Unicode char U+00E3 (decimal 227)
defining Unicode char U+00E4 (decimal 228)
defining Unicode char U+00E5 (decimal 229)
defining Unicode char U+00E6 (decimal 230)
defining Unicode char U+00E7 (decimal 231)
defining Unicode char U+00E8 (decimal 232)
defining Unicode char U+00E9 (decimal 233)
defining Unicode char U+00EA (decimal 234)
defining Unicode char U+00EB (decimal 235)
defining Unicode char U+00EC (decimal 236)
defining Unicode char U+00ED (decimal 237)
defining Unicode char U+00EE (decimal 238)
defining Unicode char U+00EF (decimal 239)
defining Unicode char U+00F0 (decimal 240)
defining Unicode char U+00F1 (decimal 241)
defining Unicode char U+00F2 (decimal 242)
defining Unicode char U+00F3 (decimal 243)
defining Unicode char U+00F4 (decimal 244)
defining Unicode char U+00F5 (decimal 245)
defining Unicode char U+00F6 (decimal 246)
defining Unicode char U+00F8 (decimal 248)
defining Unicode char U+00F9 (decimal 249)
defining Unicode char U+00FA (decimal 250)
defining Unicode char U+00FB (decimal 251)
defining Unicode char U+00FC (decimal 252)
defining Unicode char U+00FD (decimal 253)
defining Unicode char U+00FE (decimal 254)
defining Unicode char U+00FF (decimal 255)
defining Unicode char U+0100 (decimal 256)
defining Unicode char U+0101 (decimal 257)
defining Unicode char U+0102 (decimal 258)
defining Unicode char U+0103 (decimal 259)
defining Unicode char U+0104 (decimal 260)
defining Unicode char U+0105 (decimal 261)
defining Unicode char U+0106 (decimal 262)
defining Unicode char U+0107 (decimal 263)
defining Unicode char U+0108 (decimal 264)
defining Unicode char U+0109 (decimal 265)
defining Unicode char U+010A (decimal 266)
defining Unicode char U+010B (decimal 267)
defining Unicode char U+010C (decimal 268)
defining Unicode char U+010D (decimal 269)
defining Unicode char U+010E (decimal 270)
defining Unicode char U+010F (decimal 271)
defining Unicode char U+0110 (decimal 272)
defining Unicode char U+0111 (decimal 273)
defining Unicode char U+0112 (decimal 274)
defining Unicode char U+0113 (decimal 275)
defining Unicode char U+0114 (decimal 276)
defining Unicode char U+0115 (decimal 277)
defining Unicode char U+0116 (decimal 278)
defining Unicode char U+0117 (decimal 279)
defining Unicode char U+0118 (decimal 280)
defining Unicode char U+0119 (decimal 281)
defining Unicode char U+011A (decimal 282)
defining Unicode char U+011B (decimal 283)
defining Unicode char U+011C (decimal 284)
defining Unicode char U+011D (decimal 285)
defining Unicode char U+011E (decimal 286)
defining Unicode char U+011F (decimal 287)
defining Unicode char U+0120 (decimal 288)
defining Unicode char U+0121 (decimal 289)
defining Unicode char U+0122 (decimal 290)
defining Unicode char U+0123 (decimal 291)
defining Unicode char U+0124 (decimal 292)
defining Unicode char U+0125 (decimal 293)
defining Unicode char U+0128 (decimal 296)
defining Unicode char U+0129 (decimal 297)
defining Unicode char U+012A (decimal 298)
defining Unicode char U+012B (decimal 299)
defining Unicode char U+012C (decimal 300)
defining Unicode char U+012D (decimal 301)
defining Unicode char U+012E (decimal 302)
defining Unicode char U+012F (decimal 303)
defining Unicode char U+0130 (decimal 304)
defining Unicode char U+0131 (decimal 305)
defining Unicode char U+0132 (decimal 306)
defining Unicode char U+0133 (decimal 307)
defining Unicode char U+0134 (decimal 308)
defining Unicode char U+0135 (decimal 309)
defining Unicode char U+0136 (decimal 310)
defining Unicode char U+0137 (decimal 311)
defining Unicode char U+0139 (decimal 313)
defining Unicode char U+013A (decimal 314)
defining Unicode char U+013B (decimal 315)
defining Unicode char U+013C (decimal 316)
defining Unicode char U+013D (decimal 317)
defining Unicode char U+013E (decimal 318)
defining Unicode char U+0141 (decimal 321)
defining Unicode char U+0142 (decimal 322)
defining Unicode char U+0143 (decimal 323)
defining Unicode char U+0144 (decimal 324)
defining Unicode char U+0145 (decimal 325)
defining Unicode char U+0146 (decimal 326)
defining Unicode char U+0147 (decimal 327)
defining Unicode char U+0148 (decimal 328)
defining Unicode char U+014A (decimal 330)
defining Unicode char U+014B (decimal 331)
defining Unicode char U+014C (decimal 332)
defining Unicode char U+014D (decimal 333)
defining Unicode char U+014E (decimal 334)
defining Unicode char U+014F (decimal 335)
defining Unicode char U+0150 (decimal 336)
defining Unicode char U+0151 (decimal 337)
defining Unicode char U+0152 (decimal 338)
defining Unicode char U+0153 (decimal 339)
defining Unicode char U+0154 (decimal 340)
defining Unicode char U+0155 (decimal 341)
defining Unicode char U+0156 (decimal 342)
defining Unicode char U+0157 (decimal 343)
defining Unicode char U+0158 (decimal 344)
defining Unicode char U+0159 (decimal 345)
defining Unicode char U+015A (decimal 346)
defining Unicode char U+015B (decimal 347)
defining Unicode char U+015C (decimal 348)
defining Unicode char U+015D (decimal 349)
defining Unicode char U+015E (decimal 350)
defining Unicode char U+015F (decimal 351)
defining Unicode char U+0160 (decimal 352)
defining Unicode char U+0161 (decimal 353)
defining Unicode char U+0162 (decimal 354)
defining Unicode char U+0163 (decimal 355)
defining Unicode char U+0164 (decimal 356)
defining Unicode char U+0165 (decimal 357)
defining Unicode char U+0168 (decimal 360)
defining Unicode char U+0169 (decimal 361)
defining Unicode char U+016A (decimal 362)
defining Unicode char U+016B (decimal 363)
defining Unicode char U+016C (decimal 364)
defining Unicode char U+016D (decimal 365)
defining Unicode char U+016E (decimal 366)
defining Unicode char U+016F (decimal 367)
defining Unicode char U+0170 (decimal 368)
defining Unicode char U+0171 (decimal 369)
defining Unicode char U+0172 (decimal 370)
defining Unicode char U+0173 (decimal 371)
defining Unicode char U+0174 (decimal 372)
defining Unicode char U+0175 (decimal 373)
defining Unicode char U+0176 (decimal 374)
defining Unicode char U+0177 (decimal 375)
defining Unicode char U+0178 (decimal 376)
defining Unicode char U+0179 (decimal 377)
defining Unicode char U+017A (decimal 378)
defining Unicode char U+017B (decimal 379)
defining Unicode char U+017C (decimal 380)
defining Unicode char U+017D (decimal 381)
defining Unicode char U+017E (decimal 382)
defining Unicode char U+01CD (decimal 461)
defining Unicode char U+01CE (decimal 462)
defining Unicode char U+01CF (decimal 463)
defining Unicode char U+01D0 (decimal 464)
defining Unicode char U+01D1 (decimal 465)
defining Unicode char U+01D2 (decimal 466)
defining Unicode char U+01D3 (decimal 467)
defining Unicode char U+01D4 (decimal 468)
defining Unicode char U+01E2 (decimal 482)
defining Unicode char U+01E3 (decimal 483)
defining Unicode char U+01E6 (decimal 486)
defining Unicode char U+01E7 (decimal 487)
defining Unicode char U+01E8 (decimal 488)
defining Unicode char U+01E9 (decimal 489)
defining Unicode char U+01EA (decimal 490)
defining Unicode char U+01EB (decimal 491)
defining Unicode char U+01F0 (decimal 496)
defining Unicode char U+01F4 (decimal 500)
defining Unicode char U+01F5 (decimal 501)
defining Unicode char U+0218 (decimal 536)
defining Unicode char U+0219 (decimal 537)
defining Unicode char U+021A (decimal 538)
defining Unicode char U+021B (decimal 539)
defining Unicode char U+0232 (decimal 562)
defining Unicode char U+0233 (decimal 563)
defining Unicode char U+1E02 (decimal 7682)
defining Unicode char U+1E03 (decimal 7683)
defining Unicode char U+200C (decimal 8204)
defining Unicode char U+2010 (decimal 8208)
defining Unicode char U+2011 (decimal 8209)
defining Unicode char U+2012 (decimal 8210)
defining Unicode char U+2013 (decimal 8211)
defining Unicode char U+2014 (decimal 8212)
defining Unicode char U+2015 (decimal 8213)
defining Unicode char U+2018 (decimal 8216)
defining Unicode char U+2019 (decimal 8217)
defining Unicode char U+201A (decimal 8218)
defining Unicode char U+201C (decimal 8220)
defining Unicode char U+201D (decimal 8221)
defining Unicode char U+201E (decimal 8222)
defining Unicode char U+2030 (decimal 8240)
defining Unicode char U+2031 (decimal 8241)
defining Unicode char U+2039 (decimal 8249)
defining Unicode char U+203A (decimal 8250)
defining Unicode char U+2423 (decimal 9251)
defining Unicode char U+1E20 (decimal 7712)
defining Unicode char U+1E21 (decimal 7713)
)
Now handling font encoding OT1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OT1

(/ot1enc.dfu
File: ot1enc.dfu 2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
defining Unicode char U+00A0 (decimal 160)
defining Unicode char U+00A1 (decimal 161)
defining Unicode char U+00A3 (decimal 163)
defining Unicode char U+00AD (decimal 173)
defining Unicode char U+00B8 (decimal 184)
defining Unicode char U+00BF (decimal 191)
defining Unicode char U+00C5 (decimal 197)
defining Unicode char U+00C6 (decimal 198)
defining Unicode char U+00D8 (decimal 216)
defining Unicode char U+00DF (decimal 223)
defining Unicode char U+00E6 (decimal 230)
defining Unicode char U+00EC (decimal 236)
defining Unicode char U+00ED (decimal 237)
defining Unicode char U+00EE (decimal 238)
defining Unicode char U+00EF (decimal 239)
defining Unicode char U+00F8 (decimal 248)
defining Unicode char U+0131 (decimal 305)
defining Unicode char U+0141 (decimal 321)
defining Unicode char U+0142 (decimal 322)
defining Unicode char U+0152 (decimal 338)
defining Unicode char U+0153 (decimal 339)
defining Unicode char U+0174 (decimal 372)
defining Unicode char U+0175 (decimal 373)
defining Unicode char U+0176 (decimal 374)
defining Unicode char U+0177 (decimal 375)
defining Unicode char U+0218 (decimal 536)
defining Unicode char U+0219 (decimal 537)
defining Unicode char U+021A (decimal 538)
defining Unicode char U+021B (decimal 539)
defining Unicode char U+2013 (decimal 8211)
defining Unicode char U+2014 (decimal 8212)
defining Unicode char U+2018 (decimal 8216)
defining Unicode char U+2019 (decimal 8217)
defining Unicode char U+201C (decimal 8220)
defining Unicode char U+201D (decimal 8221)
)
Now handling font encoding OMS ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMS

(/omsenc.dfu
File: omsenc.dfu 2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
defining Unicode char U+00A7 (decimal 167)
defining Unicode char U+00B6 (decimal 182)
defining Unicode char U+00B7 (decimal 183)
defining Unicode char U+2020 (decimal 8224)
defining Unicode char U+2021 (decimal 8225)
defining Unicode char U+2022 (decimal 8226)
)
Now handling font encoding OMX ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMX
Now handling font encoding U ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding U
defining Unicode char U+00A9 (decimal 169)
defining Unicode char U+00AA (decimal 170)
defining Unicode char U+00AE (decimal 174)
defining Unicode char U+00BA (decimal 186)
defining Unicode char U+02C6 (decimal 710)
defining Unicode char U+02DC (decimal 732)
defining Unicode char U+200C (decimal 8204)
defining Unicode char U+2026 (decimal 8230)
defining Unicode char U+2122 (decimal 8482)
defining Unicode char U+2423 (decimal 9251)
))
(/babel.sty
Package: babel 2018/02/14 3.18 The Babel package

(/switch.def
File: switch.def 2018/02/14 3.18 Babel switching mechanism
)
*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
(/bblopts.cfg
File: bblopts.cfg 2005/09/08 v0.1 add Arabic and Farsi to "declared" options of
 babel
)
(/british.ldf
Language: british 2017/06/06 v3.3r English support from the babel system

(/english.ldf
Language: english 2017/06/06 v3.3r English support from the babel system

(/babel.def
File: babel.def 2018/02/14 3.18 Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count87
\U@D=\dimen103

(/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def)
\bbl@dirlevel=\count88
)
\l@british = a dialect from \language\l@english 
\l@UKenglish = a dialect from \language\l@english 
\l@american = a dialect from \language\l@english 
\l@canadian = a dialect from \language\l@american 
\l@australian = a dialect from \language\l@british 
\l@newzealand = a dialect from \language\l@british 
)))
(/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2017/09/02 v2.17a AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip43

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text

(/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks16
\ex@=\dimen104
))
(/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen105
)
(/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count89
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 213.
\uproot@=\count90
\leftroot@=\count91
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 375.
\classnum@=\count92
\DOTSCASE@=\count93
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 472.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 475.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 596.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box26
\strutbox@=\box27
\big@size=\dimen106
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 712.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 713.
\macc@depth=\count94
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count95
\dotsspace@=\muskip10
\c@parentequation=\count96
\dspbrk@lvl=\count97
\tag@help=\toks17
\row@=\count98
\column@=\count99
\maxfields@=\count100
\andhelp@=\toks18
\eqnshift@=\dimen107
\alignsep@=\dimen108
\tagshift@=\dimen109
\tagwidth@=\dimen110
\totwidth@=\dimen111
\lineht@=\dimen112
\@envbody=\toks19
\multlinegap=\skip44
\multlinetaggap=\skip45
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks20
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2817.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2818.
)
(/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/tools/bm.sty
Package: bm 2017/01/16 v1.2c Bold Symbol Support (DPC/FMi)
\symboldoperators=\mathgroup4
\symboldletters=\mathgroup5
\symboldsymbols=\mathgroup6
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math alphabet \mathbf on input line 141.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bm on input line 207.
)
(/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols

(/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup7
\symAMSb=\mathgroup8
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
))
(/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks21
)
(/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 99.

(/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen113
\Gin@req@width=\dimen114
)
(/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty
Package: amsthm 2017/10/31 v2.20.4
\thm@style=\toks22
\thm@bodyfont=\toks23
\thm@headfont=\toks24
\thm@notefont=\toks25
\thm@headpunct=\toks26
\thm@preskip=\skip46
\thm@postskip=\skip47
\thm@headsep=\skip48
\dth@everypar=\toks27
)
(/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/algorithms/algorithm.sty
Package: algorithm 2009/08/24 v0.1 Document Style `algorithm' - floating enviro
nment

(/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/float/float.sty
Package: float 2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
\c@float@type=\count101
\float@exts=\toks28
\float@box=\box28
\@float@everytoks=\toks29
\@floatcapt=\box29
)
(/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
\@float@every@algorithm=\toks30
\c@algorithm=\count102
)
(/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/algorithmicx/algpseudocode.sty
Package: algpseudocode 

(/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.sty
Package: algorithmicx 2005/04/27 v1.2 Algorithmicx

Document Style algorithmicx 1.2 - a greatly improved `algorithmic' style
\c@ALG@line=\count103
\c@ALG@rem=\count104
\c@ALG@nested=\count105
\ALG@tlm=\skip49
\ALG@thistlm=\skip50
\c@ALG@Lnr=\count106
\c@ALG@blocknr=\count107
\c@ALG@storecount=\count108
\c@ALG@tmpcounter=\count109
\ALG@tmplength=\skip51
)
Document Style - pseudocode environments for use with the `algorithmicx' style
) (/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/booktabs/booktabs.sty
Package: booktabs 2005/04/14 v1.61803 publication quality tables
\heavyrulewidth=\dimen115
\lightrulewidth=\dimen116
\cmidrulewidth=\dimen117
\belowrulesep=\dimen118
\belowbottomsep=\dimen119
\aboverulesep=\dimen120
\abovetopsep=\dimen121
\cmidrulesep=\dimen122
\cmidrulekern=\dimen123
\defaultaddspace=\dimen124
\@cmidla=\count110
\@cmidlb=\count111
\@aboverulesep=\dimen125
\@belowrulesep=\dimen126
\@thisruleclass=\count112
\@lastruleclass=\count113
\@thisrulewidth=\dimen127
)
(/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty
Package: longtable 2014/10/28 v4.11 Multi-page Table package (DPC)
\LTleft=\skip52
\LTright=\skip53
\LTpre=\skip54
\LTpost=\skip55
\LTchunksize=\count114
\LTcapwidth=\dimen128
\LT@head=\box30
\LT@firsthead=\box31
\LT@foot=\box32
\LT@lastfoot=\box33
\LT@cols=\count115
\LT@rows=\count116
\c@LT@tables=\count117
\c@LT@chunks=\count118
\LT@p@ftn=\toks31
) (temp.aux)
\openout1 = `temp.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 13.

(/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count119
\scratchdimen=\dimen129
\scratchbox=\box34
\nofMPsegments=\count120
\nofMParguments=\count121
\everyMPshowfont=\toks32
\MPscratchCnt=\count122
\MPscratchDim=\dimen130
\MPnumerator=\count123
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count124
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks33
) (/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf

(/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty
Package: grfext 2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)

(kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)

(/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)))
(/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)

(/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)

(/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)

(/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds) That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds) that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds) In the latter case, load this package earlier.
)))
(/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2018/01/21 v0.26 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
38.
Package grfext Info: Graphics extension search list:
(grfext) [.pdf,.png,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PDF,.PNG,.JPG,.JPE
G,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps]
(grfext) \AppendGraphicsExtensions on input line 456.
)
Overfull \hbox (8.97363pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 15--16
\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer 
of of attenuation
 []

[1

{/.miktex/texmfs/data/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] (temp.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 3977 strings out of 495223
 51837 string characters out of 3181619
 115001 words of memory out of 3000000
 7209 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 4544 words of font info for 17 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 0 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 41i,4n,26p,504b,113s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
</home
/maciej/.miktex/texmfs/install/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb></home
/maciej/.miktex/texmfs/install/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb>
Output written on temp.pdf (1 page, 23182 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 14 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: Make a complete example that can be compiled. Hyphenation depends on the complete paragraph (e.g. if a line would be underfull with a hyphenation).

Comment: your `\hyphenation` line is doing nothing as they are exactly the hyphenation points chosen by the british patterns

Comment: the hyphenation points for attenuation are found as `at-ten-u-ation`

Comment: I can't reproduce a document that fails to hyphenate the words in your list. Please, add a compilable example.

Comment: I don't get your output. Show the log-file of the compilation.

Comment: Your test file [produces this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZ5kP.png)

Comment: Your MWE gives the ouput David gets for me as well. 'pleas-ure' is hyphenated and the rest looks just fine.

Comment: To rebuild the formats go to 'MikTeX Settings (Admin)'/'MikTeX Settings' (depending on your type of installation, if you want to be extra sure, do it in both), press 'Rebuild Fomat' and wait.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your latex format is broken, the start of the log shows

```
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 0 language(s) loaded.
```

so you have no hyphenation patterns loaded for any language.

This should have given an error when the format was made, but if you force miktex to rebuild the formats then either they should report several languages being loaded, or give some error message.

I use texlive but get

```
Babel <3.17> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, this was exactly the source of the problem. I started to type my LaTeX projects on Linux recently and apparently Miktex does not work very well on it. I had to switch to the texlive and now everything runs smoothly.